# Remove certain tags in XML using Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

This is the sample code in which im trying to remove the `<notification>` and `</notification>`. I just want the `<one>` `<two>` tags.

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import java.util.*

def s_xml=new StringWriter()
def builder = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(s_xml)
def tempMap = [one:'yes', two: 'Java', three:'Scala']
builder.notification{
        tempMap.each(){ key, value ->
          "${key}""${value}"
        }
}
log.info s_xml
```

output:

```
<notification>
  <one>Groovy1</one>
  <two>Java</two>
  <three>Scala</three>
</notification>
```

i want the output as:

```
 <one>Groovy1</one>
 <two>Java</two>
 <three>Scala</three>
```

If I remove the `.notification` from `builder.notification{`, the output becomes:

```
<call>
  <one>yes</one>
  <two>Java</two>
  <three>Scala</three>
</call>
```

so by default it puts a tag which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please consider that every xml-document has a root node [wikipedia: root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element)

if you don't want it, concat it "by hand":

```
String sXml = ""
tempMap.each { key, value ->
    sXml += "<$key>$value</$key>"
}
```

or if you would like to use a StringBuilder:

```
def sXml = ''<<''
tempMap.each { key, value ->
    sXml << "<$key>$value</$key>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MarkupBuilder's `with` method so it doesn't generate a `call` root node:

```
import groovy.xml.* 

sw = new StringWriter()
mb = new MarkupBuilder(sw).with {
    one "java"
    two "groovy"
}

assert sw.toString() == """<one>java</one>
<two>groovy</two>"""
```

Source: [groovy's mailing list](http://user.groovy.codehaus.narkive.com/mrXNHqas/groovy-user-markupbuilder-without-root).